# Map to Piecharts - Amcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, maps, amcharts

I am trying to customize this chart demo by Amcharts:

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/countries-morphing-to-pie-charts/

I cannot figure out how and where I can give my data as input. I see that the example uses random data for the pie charts, setting them with this line of code:

```
dataItem.value = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
```

I need to have custom values for the piechart of each country in the chart.

Maybe I have to edit these lines of code:

```
var pieSeries = pieChart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "category";
pieSeries.data = [{ value: 100, category: "First" }, { value: 20, category: "Second" }, { value: 10, category: "Third" }];
```

But How? I would like to pass the data as an array of a JSON, but the format is not a real problem.

Do you have any idea?

Thanke you.

Comment: You want to push on `pieSeries.data` multiples JSON with value and category? how many specifically?

Comment: Hi, I would like to have data for each country, I have to use different JSON files or variables to do that?

Comment: @LeandroMatilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have info about the country on the `hit` event:
`event.target.dataItem.dataContext.id`.
The `id` field represents the country code.

so you can use it in the `showPieChart(polygon)` function to retrieve specific data from the country code.
you will get the country code in that function from `polygon.dataItem.dataContext.id`

so, for example, build your data:

```
let myData = {'ES': [{value: 51, category: 'first'}, {value: 99, category: 'second'}, { value: 4, category: "Third" }], 'FR': [{value: 80, category: 'first'}, {value: 20, category: 'second'}, { value: 23, category: "Third"}];
```

and than, replace the `dataItem.value = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);` with:

```
dataItem.value = myData[polygon.dataItem.dataContext.id][i].value;
```